# Style UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, customization

I need to style a grouped TableView. I found this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2033/core-graphics-101-lines-rectangles-and-gradients. But unfortunately the simple version (with the red) doesn't work for me. I'm using ARC, therefore one line of code

`cell.backgroundView = [[[CustomCellBackground alloc] init] autorelease];
 cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[[CustomCellBackground alloc] init] autorelease];`

doesn't work. What's the ARC version of the code above. I am using prototype cells in the storyboard. Maybe that's the reason for it.

Answer (score 1):

ARC doesn't use `autorelease`, so just type :

```
cell.backgroundView = [[CustomCellBackground alloc] init];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[CustomCellBackground alloc] init];
```

Comment: Yes, I did this. But still it doesn't work. I don't get any errors...it just doesn't work..Is that due to the storyboard?

Comment: Could you explain what "doesn't work"? Error messages? Description of what happens? Code segments? - "Doesn't work" is not very helpful.

Comment: I got working right now, so that I can change the colour of the cells...but the rounded corners from the default grouped style are gone..is that normal because I'm using the draw rect funktion?